# I lost the source files for iOS and Android application`s code, I have the latest apk & the latest built in the test flight, is there a way to get it

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to extract the source of the code from the builts, it`s written in Flutter languge, so both code should be similer

I tried to follow these steps, but it showes me that there`s no java file
[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: No. While you could try and disassemble the binary, nothing is going to get you dart code back.  You can't unmake the sausage.